# laravel password and confirm password can not work

Tags: laravel

I am validation rule in laravel view all  validation rule but password and confirm  password can not match if i am giving same password in both field. What is mistake done by me i am using custom message to both field.

blade:

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="inputPassword">Password</label>
                      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password">
                       <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('password') }}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="inputCPassword">Password</label>
                      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputCPassword" placeholder="Enter Confirm Password" name="cpassword">
                      </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

controller:

```
public function store(Request $req)
    {
        $user=new Users;
        $mytime = Carbon::now();
        $user->updated_at=$mytime->toDateTimeString();
        $user->created_at=$mytime->toDateTimeString(); 
        $user->name=$req->input('name');
        $user->email=$req->input('email');
        $user->password=$req->input('password');
        $user->cpassword=$req->input('cpassword');
        $user->mobile_number=$req->input('mobile_number');

        $messages = [
               'password.confirmed' => 'Your passwords were mismatched',
               'cpassword.min' => 'Your password must be at least 4 characters'
                    ];

        $rules=[
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:table_users',
        'mobile_number' => 'required|unique:table_users',
        'password' => 'min:4|confirmed',
        'cpassword'   => 'min:4|confirmed',
        ];

        $this->validate($req, $rules, $messages);

        $user->save();

        return redirect('login')->with('success',"You have successfully submitted data & now you can login");
```

Comment: confirm password field name should be password_confirmation https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-confirmed

Comment: Hello, there could be lot's of stuff preventing the save. Does your User Model have fillable array includes email, mobile_number and other required areas? This might be a mass assignment issue. Please check https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#mass-assignment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel validation `'password' => 'min:4|confirmed',`

it means it will look for this field to match  `password_confirmation`

example

for `'foo' => 'min:4|confirmed',`

it will look for a input file `name="foo_confirmation"` so here `foo` should match with `foo_confirmation` field

ref link
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-confirmed

---

in you case you need to change

```php
$rules = [
    'name' => 'required',
    'email' => 'required|email|unique:table_users',
    'mobile_number' => 'required|unique:table_users',
    'password' => 'min:4|confirmed',
];
```

remove `cpassword`

and

```
<input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputCPassword" placeholder="Enter Confirm Password" name="cpassword">
```

to

```php
<input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputCPassword" placeholder="Enter Confirm Password" name="password_confirmation">
```

name `cpassword` to `password_confirmation`

Comment: $query_select=DB::select('select * from table_users where email=? && password= ? or mobile_number=? && password= ?',[$email_address,$password,$email_address,$password]);  how can i fetch name from this array